# Retrieve data from tables using join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables X and Y, I want to return the data from table Y where `X.id=Y.id` and from table X, I want to return only those rows where `X.id!=Y.id`.

I have written a query

```
Select * from X left join Y on X.id=Y.id
```

but that would return me all the rows from table X where as I want only those where `X.id!=Y.id`.

How would I do that? I hope the questions is understandable.

Comment: This question blew my mind. I did not understand a thing. Maybe an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: `X.id!=Y.id` or `X.id=Y.id` ? which one is it?

Comment: have you tried `Select * from X left join Y where X.id=Y.id`

Comment: you need common field (usually primary key in one table connect with foreign key in another). if values in ON clause are not the same, on what ground would you link two tables? Do you know what JOIN is used for?

Comment: Well, let's pretend you get data from Y based on condition X.id=Y.id, and from X based on condition X.id!=Y.id. How do you want to connect these two different datasets?

Comment: You want all the rows from X where ids don't appear at all in Y, is that it?

Comment: Also, do you want the ids only?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. _I want to return only those rows where `X.id!=Y.id`_ Perhaps you need to read up on what a `JOIN` actually does. This might make you rephrase your question. **Otherwise**, I suggest that you give examples of tables `X` and `Y` and the desired query result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from X right join Y on X.ID=Y.ID
```

OR

```
select * from Y left join X on X.ID=Y.ID
```

Then you get all rows from Y and  those which are referenced in X-table and all data from X-table which have reference in Y.

Was this your question?

Other answer I can see in this question is

```
with cte (X.ID,Y.ID)
as(
select x.ID,y.ID from X INNER JOIN Y ON X.ID=Y.ID
)
select * from Y  JOIN cte 
where t.id not in (cte.Y.ID)
UNION ALL
select * from cte
```

Something like that (Might need some debugging was written without SQL Management or SQL Developper :) )

Answer (score 0):

All the rows of Y for which there's an existing id in X:

```
SELECT Y.*
FROM Y 
INNER JOIN X
USING(id)
```

All the rows of X for which there isn't an existing id in Y

```
SELECT X.* 
FROM X 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM Y
)
```

If the output columns are the same, you could do an UNION of both queries.

Answer (score 0):

Let say we have two tables mentioned as:-

select * from cmp_Company as x

select * from cmp_Company_Contact as y

Case A: [All the rows returned from Y table]

select 
    Y.*
from
cmp_Company_Contact as Y
LEFT JOIN cmp_Company as X ON X.CO_ID = Y.CO_ID
where
X.CO_ID = Y.CO_ID

Case B: [No rows is returned from X table]

select 
    X.CO_Name
from
cmp_Company as X
LEFT JOIN cmp_Company_Contact as Y ON Y.CO_ID = X.CO_ID
where
**X.CO_ID != Y.CO_ID**

So based on the condition that your are asking for , no data will be achieved.

Hope it helps.

Thanks